# SurveyMonkey creating a collector in Powershell returning "The body provided was not a proper JSON string

Tags: json, powershell, surveymonkey

I'm using Powershell to automate a survey creation, adding a collector, and sending the survey invitation - a pretty common use case.  I was able to create a survey but I'm running into an issue in creating the collector.  I created a collector via Postman but I get the error `"1001 - The body provided was not a property JSON string"` when using Powershell. I've tried everything I can think of but continue to get the error no matter how I create the JSON. Here is the code I'm using:

```
$SurveyCollector = [PSCustomObject]@{ type = 'email' } 

$BodyText = $SurveyCollector | Select-Object -Property type |ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100 -Compress 

$Results = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -StatusCodeVariable "ExtIDscv" -SkipHttpErrorChe -Method 
Post -ContentType "application/json" -Authentication Bearer -Token $SecureToken -body -$BodyText
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: There should be no space in `Bearer-Token`

Answer (score 0):

The answer was more simple than what tripleee suggested.  I had introduced a -$BodyText into the call and didn't catch it.  I removed it and it works just fine.

$Results = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -StatusCodeVariable "ExtIDscv" -SkipHttpErrorChe -Method
Post -ContentType "application/json" -Authentication Bearer -Token $SecureToken -body -$BodyText